# Parse.com binding to a listview ItemSource How

Tags: c#, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

How do i call this method correclty to a databound listview I am having this in dal class.How would I also adpat the query to handle Lists from different users?.

```
public async Task<List<MagicLists>> GetListsAync()
    {
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("lists");
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> result = new List<ParseObject>();
        try
        {
            result = await query.FindAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        var listItems = new List<MagicLists>();
        foreach (var listItemParseObject in result)
        {
            var listItem = await MagicLists.CreateFromParseObject(listItemParseObject);
            listItems.Add(listItem);
        }
        return listItems;
}
```

Then I am calling it using

```
MagicListsDal _db = new MagicListsDal();

listItems.ItemsSource = _db.GetListsAync();
```

But as you no that does not work i get an error on compile

> Error    2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\PhoneApps\WorldClock2\WordClocks\WordClocks\MagicLists.xaml.cs   23  37  MagicLists

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to await the task:

```
listItems.ItemsSource = await _db.GetListsAync();
```

Note that to use the `await` keyboard, you also have to mark your method with the `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get result from task

```
MagicListsDal _db = new MagicListsDal();

listItems.ItemsSource = _db.GetListsAync().Result;
```

Comment: Do i just using {BindingSource} then as itemsource to bind it to listview xaml ? also how would i adapat the query to bring back list from specific user